How to get notified when a partition is mounted or unmounted in RPi OS and Python?
I tried the following code and I am not getting any notification when mounting and unmounting partitions. Am I missing something ?
I use the library pyinotify to watch the changes in the file /proc/mounts... but it seems that my handler is never called...
import pyinotify, time

# Define a callback function to handle file system events
class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_MODIFY(self, event):
        print(f"Change detected in {event.pathname}!")

# Create an inotify instance
wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()

# Create an event handler instance
handler = EventHandler()

# Create an inotify notifier and pass the function as the event handler
notifier = pyinotify.ThreadedNotifier(wm, handler)

# Watch for changes to /proc/mounts
wm.add_watch("/proc/mounts", pyinotify.IN_MODIFY)

# Start the notifier loop
print("Watching for mount changes...")
notifier.start()

try:
  while True:
    time.sleep(1)
except: pass

notifier.stop()
print('Done!')


Sorry - I don't have the time to research it properly now, but you will likely have to use DBUS for that: https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html

I've just checked that the dbus-monitor --system  actually lists mount/umount events - so it would work -

I need to study dbus as I never worked with it...

@jsbueno there are a lot of signals when I mound and unmount a partition... I donțt know for which one should I listen to receive a notification only at mount/unmount and not at other system events...

This is how I solved the problem. With this code I get a single notification every time a block device (USB HDD) is connected or disconected, and when a partition is mounted or unmounted. I am not 100% sure that the callback is not triggered on other cases too, but if so, the dbus signal filter can be adjusted...
import time, threading

class FastTimer(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, interval, callback, args=None, kwargs=None, shots=1):
    super().__init__()
    self.daemon = True
    self.interval = interval
    self.callback = callback
    self.args = args if args is not None else []
    self.kwargs = kwargs if kwargs is not None else {}
    self.last_shot = shots
    self.trigger = threading.Event()
    self.done = threading.Event()
    self.terminated = threading.Event()
    self.start()

  def Terminate(self):
    if self.is_alive():
      self.terminated.set()
      self.done.set()
      self.trigger.set()
      self.join()

  def Gooo(self):
    if self.is_alive():
      self.trigger.set()

  def Abort(self):
    if self.is_alive():
      self.done.set()
      self.trigger.clear()

  def Reset(self):
    if self.is_alive():
      self.done.set()

  def Mark(self):
    if self.is_alive():
      if self.trigger.is_set(): self.done.set()
      else: self.trigger.set()

  def run(self):
    while not self.terminated.is_set():
      if not self.trigger.is_set():
        shot = 0; self.done.clear()
      self.trigger.wait()
      Reseted = self.done.wait(self.interval)
      self.done.clear()
      if self.terminated.is_set(): break
      if not Reseted:
        self.callback(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        if self.last_shot > 0:
          shot += 1
          if shot == self.last_shot:
            self.trigger.clear()
    print('Timer terminated.')


class BlockDevMonitor(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, callback, args=None, kwargs=None):
    import time
    super().__init__()
    self.loop = None
    self.timer = FastTimer(1, callback, args, kwargs)
    self.start()
    time.sleep(0.3)

  def Terminate(self):
    if self.is_alive():
      if self.loop != None: self.loop.quit()
      self.join()
    self.timer.Terminate()

  def run(self):
    import dbus
    from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
    from gi.repository import GLib

    def sigUnitChg(*args):
      if (len(args) >= 1) and ( args[0].startswith('blockdev@') or ('-block-' in args[0]) ): self.timer.Mark()

    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    self.loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    bus.add_signal_receiver(sigUnitChg, dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager', signal_name='UnitNew', path='/org/freedesktop/systemd1')
    bus.add_signal_receiver(sigUnitChg, dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager', signal_name='UnitRemoved', path='/org/freedesktop/systemd1')

    print('DevMonitor started.')
    self.loop.run()
    print('DevMonitor stopped.')


#----------------------------------------------

def OnUpdate():
  print('Device Manager updated !')

DevMon = BlockDevMonitor(OnUpdate)

try:
  i = 0
  while True:
    time.sleep(1);
    i += 1; print(i)
except:
  pass

DevMon.Terminate()

